# Conditionnel ou futur dans le discours indirect

Tags: conditionnel, discours-indirect

J'hésite entre plusieurs constructions dans l'exemple suivant :

« pourriez vous préciser  si je devrai(s) venir à votre bureau pour signer le document ou sinon il me faudra(it) vous envoyer une copie ?»

Quelle est la différence entre « devrai », « devrais » ou « dois » dans la première partie et « faudrai(t) » dans la deuxième ?

Comment: Personnellement, j'utiliserais le présent de l'indicatif ici, mais c'est aussi une question de goût *Pourriez-vous préciser si je dois venir ...*, sauf bien sûr si l'échéance est lointaine

Comment: D’accord merci ! Donc , à priori, toutes les trois formes sont possible dans ce cas , n’est pas ? Il s’agit d’une absence de règles pour le discours indirect , sachant que j’ai commencé la première partie par conditionnel présent (pourrez vous..)

Answer (score 1):

Tous les temps évoqués sont possibles avec des nuances de sens :

> Pourriez vous préciser si je **dois** venir à votre bureau pour signer le document ?

On peut éventuellement y aller tout de suite.

> Pourriez vous préciser si je **devrai** venir à votre bureau pour signer le document ?

On ne pourra y aller que plus tard.

> Pourriez vous préciser si je **devrais** venir à votre bureau pour signer le document ?

Là, on demande uniquement un conseil alors que précédemment, il s'agissait plus d'une directive.

La fin de la phrase n'est pas très heureuse :

> ...ou sinon il me faudra(it) vous envoyer une copie.

Ce sera plutôt :

> Pourriez vous préciser si je dois/devrai venir à votre bureau pour signer le document ou (alors) si je peux/pourrai vous envoyer une copie ?

ou

> Pourriez vous préciser si je devrais venir à votre bureau pour signer le document ou si vous envoyer une copie suffirait?

Comment: Un grand merci de ces exemples très utiles ! 
Oui effectivement, je doutais de la deuxième partie « ou sinon il me faudra(it) vous envoyer.. » . En fait je croyais que ce serait possible de dire en utilisant «il me faudrait » mais probablement cela ne marche pas dans ce cas particulier...